# How do I make this slide show more dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, css

SlideShow with JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
    var pictures = document.getElementsByClassName("my-slides");
var nextArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("next");
var prevArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("prev");
var lines = document.getElementsByClassName("line");



pictures[0].style.display="block";

var n = 1;
lines[n-1].classList.add("yellow-lines");
nextArrow[0].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[n].style.display="block";
        lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
        lines[n].classList.remove("green-lines");
        lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
        lines[n].classList.add("yellow-lines");
    }
    n++;
    if(n == pictures.length)
    {
        n=0;
    }
}

var p = pictures.length - 1;
prevArrow[0].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[p].style.display="block";
        lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
        lines[p].classList.remove("green-lines");
        lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
        lines[p].classList.add("yellow-lines");
    }
    p--;
    if(p == - 1)
    {
        p = pictures.length - 1;
    }
}

lines[0].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[0].style.display="block";
        lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
        lines[0].classList.remove("green-lines");
        lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
        lines[0].classList.add("yellow-lines");
    }
}

lines[1].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[1].style.display="block";
        lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
        lines[1].classList.remove("green-lines");
        lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
        lines[1].classList.add("yellow-lines");
    }
}

lines[2].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[2].style.display="block";
        lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
        lines[1].classList.remove("green-lines");
        lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
        lines[1].classList.add("yellow-lines");
    }
}



var s = 1;
function automaticSlideShowCounter()
{
        if (s == 0)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
            {
                pictures[i].style.display="none";
                pictures[0].style.display="block";
                lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
                lines[0].classList.remove("green-lines");
                lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
                lines[0].classList.add("yellow-lines");
            }
        }
        if (s == 1)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
            {
                pictures[i].style.display="none";
                pictures[1].style.display="block";
                lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
                lines[1].classList.remove("green-lines");
                lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
                lines[1].classList.add("yellow-lines");
            }
        }
        if (s == 2)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
            {
                pictures[i].style.display="none";
                pictures[2].style.display="block";
                lines[i].classList.add("green-lines");
                lines[2].classList.remove("green-lines");
                lines[i].classList.remove("yellow-lines");
                lines[2].classList.add("yellow-lines");
                s = -1;
            }
        }
        s++;
}



function automaticSlideShow()
{
    setInterval(automaticSlideShowCounter, 2500);
}

automaticSlideShow();
```

HTML code:

```
    <div class="main-slideShow-div">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="my-slides">
          <img class="pic" src="images/animals/dog1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="my-slides">
          <img class="pic" src="images/animals/dog2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="my-slides">
          <img class="pic" src="images/animals/dog3.jpg">
        </div>
        <img class="prev" src="images/leftArrow.png" alt="leftArrow">
        <img class="next" src="images/rightArrow.png" alt="rightArrow">
        <div class="slider-div" style="text-align:center">
          <div id="lines" class="line"></div>
          <div id="lines2" class="line"></div>
          <div id="lines3" class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code for `green-lines` and `yellow-lines`

```
.yellow-lines{
    background-color: #ff0;
}

.green-lines{
    background-color: #2daf2d;
}
```

So now everything is done, the code you see above is the edited and working code, thanks for helping! :D

(Sorry if I couldn't format the code here how it should be done.)

Comment: Try to keep your question focussed on a single issue. You say you can't seem to figure out the part about for loops. Could you show us an attempt where you try to figure it out? Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3t4ury5s/2/
Here is what I made, I'm aware that it doesnt work, but im not sure how should I turn on just one of these and off the rest.

Comment: And here is another one https://jsfiddle.net/3t4ury5s/6/

Comment: Okaaaay, I cant believe that, but looks like I solved the for loop problem: https://jsfiddle.net/3t4ury5s/7/

Comment: I have updated the post, now only one problem remains.

Comment: Well done! As for the hover effects. Avoid using inline styles: `style.backgroundColor = '2DAF2D';` will set a style attribute on the element, which has a higher precedence over regular styles. Add and remove classes instead to keep your CSS in control. For example: `pictures[i].classList.add('active');`

Comment: Thanks, but if I add a class, then how do I add styles to it? Can I style it in CSS and then just adding it to the element when clicking on it with JavaScript, or what do you mean exactly? I dont quite get it.

Comment: Write the styles as CSS in your stylesheet. For example `.active { background-color: #2DAF2D; }`. Then when you add the `active` class to an element, the styles from that class will be applied to that element.

Comment: Okay, now that works, but it doesnt have the "position" color or whatever is that, I mean, the hover effect now works, but because of the new class it doesnt turn yellow after clicking on a line.

Comment: And if I set the background color to yellow in CSS, then it sets all of the lines to yellow when clicking on one.

Comment: Okay, looks like after a few minutes I figured it out once more, so I will update the code in the post if anyone interested.
Thanks a lot for your help, couldn't do it without you :D!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230204/discussion-between-idontknowhowtocode-and-emiel-zuurbier).